# .htaccess rewriting old RSS feed URL to WordPress feed URL

Tags: htaccess, feed

I migrated my old site to WordPress, and I tought rewriting old RSS URL will be easy. Nope. My old RSS feed was served on /rss.php URL. So I added to .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^rss\.php$ /feed/ [L]
```

And now I get 404 error page for rss.php. What's important: I don't want *redirection* ([R]), I want URL rewrite, so old /rss.php path will work unchanged.

Well, rule changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^rss\.php$ index.php?feed=rss2 [L]
```

Now I get some broken / empty feed page with `mydomain.com/rss.php/feed/` URL (so it is somehow redirected).

Is there any way how to serve WordPress feeds on custom URL with .htaccess rewrite?